# how to add second parameter in RedirectToAction new{}?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, parameters

i have a RedirectToAction in some of Controller.
i need second parameter in it, but all my attempts flopps.

here is orogin code which works just with one parameter.

```
RedirectToAction("Rating", "contract", new { partnerUsername = partnerUsername });
```

second should be: `?page=2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RedirectToAction("Rating", "contract", new { partnerUsername = partnerUsername, page = 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as many as parameters you want all you have to do is separate them with commas like this

```
RedirectToAction("Rating", "contract", new { partnerUsername = partnerUsername, page = 2 });
```